# Forming a committee from groups with conditions

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

There are three groups of 10 individuals - 30 individuals in total.

From these, choose 10 individuals, including at least 2 from each group.

It seems to me that the answer to this should be $C(10,2)*C(10,2)*C(10,2)*C(24,4)$,
where C(10,2) is the choice of 2 individuals from each group, and $C(24,4)$ is the choice of 4 individuals from the remaining $24$.

Apparently, this is not correct.
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You made the same type of error discussed in [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4317983/choosing-at-least-2-women-from-7-men-and-4-women/4318002#4318002).

Comment: Does these answers help you ?

Answer (score 1):

Directly:
$$\sum_{i=2}^6 \sum_{j=2}^{8 - i} \binom{10}{i} \binom{10}{j} \binom{10}{10-i-j} = 24466050$$

---

Via inclusion-exclusion, where the three properties to be avoided are that group $g$ has fewer than two individuals selected:
\begin{align}
&\binom{30}{10}-\binom{3}{1}\left[\binom{10}{0}\binom{20}{10}+\binom{10}{1}\binom{20}{9}\right]+\binom{3}{2}\left[\binom{10}{0}^2\binom{10}{10}+\binom{2}{1}\binom{10}{0}\binom{10}{1}\binom{10}{9}+\binom{10}{1}^2 \binom{10}{8}\right] \\
&= 30045015 - 5593068 + 14103 \\
&= 24466050\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

"What is my mistake ?" : You are making overcounting.Your combination calculating is prone to count one individual more than once

You can get rid of overcounting by using *[generating functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function)* such that

If there will be at least $2$ people from each group , then a group can give at most $6$ people.

The generating function of a group is $$(C(10,2)x^2 +C(10,3)x^3+C(10,4)x^4+C(10,5)x^5+C(10,6)x^6)$$

Then , now find $$[x^{10}](C(10,2)x^2 +C(10,3)x^3+C(10,4)x^4+C(10,5)x^5+C(10,6)x^6)^3$$
Understand the logic , when we expand it , we choose one term from each pharenteses where each pharenteses represent the groups. For example , one of the possible exponential selection is $3-2-5$ ,it means that we select $3$ people form the first group , $2$ people from the second group , $5$ people from the last group.So , one of the coefficient of $x^{10}$ is $C(10,3) C(10,2) C(10,5)$ .When we expand it with wolfram and look at the coefficient of $x^{10}$ ,we see the summation of all possible combinations.

*[SEE EXPANSION](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expanded+form+of+%2845x%5E2+%2B120x%5E3+%2B+210x%5E4+%2B+252x%5E5+%2B210x%5E6%29%5E3) *

So , answer is $24,466,050$