# A committee of 11 members is to be formed from 8 males and 5 females with at least 6 males in the committee

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, binomial-coefficients

Q) A committee of 11 members is to be formed from 8 males and 5 females. The number of ways the committee is formed with at least 6 males is?

The general solution I see everywhere is to take 3 cases where there are 6 males, 7 males and 8 males.

What I want to know is why the following logic is wrong:

1. Select 6 males from 8: $\binom{8}{6}$
2. Now since all conditions are satisfied select the remaining members for the committee($ 11-6=5 $) from the remaining total($(8+5)-6 = 7$): $\binom{7}{5}$

This gives the answer $$\binom{8}{6} * \binom{7}{5} = 588$$ but the required answer is 68.

Comment: You are overcounting the cases with more than $6$ males.  If your group has $8$ males, say, there's no way to tell which of them were part of the special $6$.

Comment: Repetitions. Let's name the M1 to M8 and F1 to F5. Let's take the first 6 to be M1-M6 and later 5 to be M7, M8 and F1-F3. Now instead you could take first 6 to be M3-M8 and next 5 to be M1, M2 and F1-F3. Both will give you same group at the end but they are both counted in your process.

Comment: Better yet, see [Choosing at least $2$ women from $7$ men and $4$ women](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4317983/choosing-at-least-2-women-from-7-men-and-4-women/4318002#4318002).

Comment: Btw, the answer you quote is incorrect, maybe a typo. You should work out what the correct answer is.

Answer (score -1):

when you choose 6 out of 8 males, this means you mark every make either as "Yes" or "No". if you then choose 5 out of the remaining 7 (2 males and 5), each of them gets another label "Yes" or "No", so essentially some males will get multiple labels - "No+No" or "No+Yes". So your approach distinguishes between males with "Yes" and males with "No-Yes"